# Discord.py channel.connect() never returns

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I am currently working on a discord.py-rewrite (1.3.3) bot for my discord server. At the moment, I am trying to make the bot play music in the voice channels. According to the discord.py documentation, you would use the function [channel.connect()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=connect#discord.VoiceChannel.connect) to connect to a voice channel, which would return a [VoiceClient](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=connect#discord.VoiceClient) object.

However, I never get a VoiceClient object back from channel.connect(). The bot does join my channel, but it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop. Nothing after the line "await channel.connect()" is executed, so the line "test" is not printed. When I update the bot's role in the server it works **once**, but after i restart the bot it will no longer work.

```
# This is just a function, not the command the user calls. The context is passed through
async def join(ctx):
    voice_status = ctx.author.voice

    # Checking if author voice_status is not none
    if voice_status:
        # Getting the channel of the author
        channel = voice_status.channel

        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            # Connect the bot
            vc = await channel.connect()
            print("test")
```

I have found a few threads on github and overflow where people were experiencing the same problem, but they never fixed it. I'm quite sure that the code is correct.

I have already tried reinstalling and updating discord.py. I have also asked for help in the discord API server but they could not replicate my issue.

This is my first overflow post so I apologize in advance if there is anything wrong with my post.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to make your bot join a voice channel:

```py
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    if not channel:
        await ctx.send("You're not connected to any voice channel !")
    else:
        voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()
```

PS : if you add a `play` command, you'll still have to get the bot's channel and voice with those to lines :

```py
voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
```

Comment: This worked a few times, but now it doesn't anymore. It seems to be random.

Comment: Do you have any error message when it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: No, it doesn't throw any exceptions. It is simply stuck at the connect() line.

Answer (score 0):

I removed your comments and added my own `#comments`

```
voice_status = ctx.author.voice
if voice_status:  # this check does nothing. This is a discord.VoiceState object
  channel = voice_status.channel
  # channel is None if you are not connected to a voice channel
  # channel is a Channel object if you are connected to a voice channel
  if ctx.voice_client is None:
  # I may be wrong but if I read the docs right this returns the voice client of the guild, something semi-related to the author.
    vc = await channel.connect()
    # You are not connected to a voice channel. So channel is None. Now you are trying to connect to a None channel.
    print("test")
```

Comment: I check if voice_status is none, because if it is, channel doest not exist. If I then try to get ctx.author.voice.channel you get an attribute error.

Answer (score 0):

ik this is old, but I've spend a long time fixing the problem myself and I haven't found any answers online. My problem was that my bot didn't have the Intents for voice stuff. If your bot is just for a small group of people like your friends, just settings `intents` to `discord.Intents.all()` will work. Otherwise you can manually select them.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem discord RTC. Your bot try to connect but rtc is blocked by firewall. You should anable DNS UDP in firewall.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33319760)

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I just found another solution for this problem after working on it for a few days.

Make sure discord libraries are up to date.

Run in terminal:
`pip install discord --upgrade` and `pip install discord-ext-bot --upgrade`

Hope this helps.