# discord.VoiceChannel.connect() not returning anything

Tags: python, discord, coroutine

I'm making a discord bot that connects to a voice channel that the caller currently is in. I'm using **connect()** library call to connect the bot.
According to [Discord API documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=connect#discord.VoiceChannel.connect), **connect()** must return a VoiceProtocol. However, the call hangs and never actually returns anything.

There is an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62557255/discord-py-channel-connect-never-returns) from 2021, asking the same question without any concrete solutions.

For Example:

```
caller = ctx.author.voice
        if caller is None:
            await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
            return 
        else:
            await caller.connect(timeout=.5, reconnect=False, self_mute=False, self_deaf=True)
            await ctx.send("This line never executes")
```

Even though the call doesn't return anything, it still connects the bot to a voice channel without raising any exceptions.

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue before.

**EDIT:** is_connected() library call also returns False. So, although the bot is indeed connected to a voice channel, it thinks that it is not connected.

```
@commands.command()
async def isconnected(self, ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(ctx.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    print("is_connected(): ", voice.is_connected())

    _id = voice.channel.id
    print("bot is connected to channel: " + str(ctx.bot.get_channel(_id)))

    voice2 = discord.utils.get(self.client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    print("is_connected(): ",  voice2.is_connected())

    _id2 = voice2.channel.id
    print("bot is connected to channel: ", str(ctx.bot.get_channel(_id2)))

@commands.command()
async def join(self, ctx):
    caller = ctx.message.author.voice
    if caller is None:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
        return
    await caller.channel.connect(timeout=5, reconnect=False, self_mute=False, self_deaf=True)
    print("Never executes")
```

Terminal output:
[image]

Comment: What version of discordpy are you using?

Comment: version is 2.1.0

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v2.1.0/discord/voice_client.py#L370) for 2.1.0 shows that `connect` wouldn't return anything. Maybe the documentation wasn't updated to reflect that. I'm not sure why it hangs though. Have you tried using a longer timeout?

Comment: The longer timeout doesn't help. However, the last line did execute after a several minute delay. On the other note, is_connected() call returns False despite the bot being connected to a voice chat. This is bizarre. I will update my post.

Comment: I'm getting exactly this same behavior with my bot.  The bot is in the channel as far as discord is concerned, but is_connected() is false, and the connect call isn't returning.  If you were able to solve your problem, please return and self-answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue with discord-py 2.1.0 as well. Upgrading to the latest version (2.2.2) solved this problem for me. Here is the command I ran to upgrade with pip:

```
pip install -U --upgrade-strategy eager discord-py
```

I investigated further as to why this happened but could not identify the root cause. The implementation for VoiceChannel in [2.1.0](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v2.1.0/discord/channel.py#L986) and [2.2.2](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v2.2.2/discord/channel.py#L1242) both implement the [Connectable protocol](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v2.2.2/discord/abc.py#L1821) which doesn't seem to have changed between these two versions. If anyone else can identify the root cause I am open ears.

Comment: In my case the issue was having a slow internet connection as I was downloading something else in the background. I think in general such issues are related to having outdated discord version or slow internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, however when I enabled logging output in discord.py this popped up.

`WARNING  discord.client PyNaCl is not installed, voice will NOT be supported`

Installing PyNaCl solved the issue.