# Unable to assign a discord bot the voice channel it has connected to

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to learn how to code a bot using discord.py and I'm following a youtube tutorial by Dasma tech on how to create a music bot.

I have gotten to the point where the bot can join the voice channel of the person that sent the command but, when assigning the dictionary "self.vc[id] = await channel.connect()" it isn't being assigned.

I have gone through the code multiple times and it is the same as Dasma Tech's and there aren't any errors when running the code.

I am running the code on a Raspberry pi 5 if that is of any help.

[What is outputted to terminal after using the command in discord while connected to a voice channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Ngy.png)

When testing for the problem I added a print before and after calling the function join_VC, with the first print working but the print after doesn't and I cant figure out why. The print in join_VC just after assigning and the ctx.send after calling join_VC, also aren't being outputted either.

I believe the problem with assigning self.vc[id] is stopping the bot from being able to leave the voice channel when using the leave command, since it does not know what it is connected to since the default value of self.vc[id] is None.

Code:

```
import discord
from discord_components import Select, SelectOption, Button
import discord.ext
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from asyncio import run_coroutine_threadsafe
from urllib import parse, request
import re
import json
import os
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
        self.is_playing = {}
        self.is_paused = {}
        self.musicQueue = {}
        self.queueIndex = {}
        
        self.YTDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'nonplaylist': 'True'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        
        self.embedBlue = 0x2c76dd
        self.embedRed = 0xdf1141
        self.embedGreen = 0x0eaa51
        
        self.vc = {}
        
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            id = int(guild.id)
            self.musicQueue[id] = []
            self.queueIndex[id] = 0
            self.vc[id] = None
            self.is_paused[id] = self.is_playing[id] = False
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):
        id = int(member.guild.id)
        if member.id != self.bot.user.id and before.channel != None and after.channel != before.channel:
            remainingChannelMembers = before.channel.members
            if len(remainingChannelMembers) == 1 and remainingChannelMembers[0].id == self.bot.user.id and self.vc[id].is_connected():
                self.is_playing[id] = self.is_paused[id] = False
                self.musicQueue[id] = []
                self.queueIndex[id] = 0
                await self.vc[id].disconnect()
        
    def now_playing_embed(self, ctx, song):
        title = song['title']
        link = song['link']
        thumbnail = song['thumbnail']
        author = ctx.author
        avatar = author.avatar_url
        
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "Now Playing",
            description=f'[{title}]({link})',
            colour = self.embedGreen
        )
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=thumbnail)
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Song added by: {str(author)}', icon_url=avatar)
        return embed
            
    async def join_VC(self, ctx, channel):
        id = int(ctx.guild.id)
        if self.vc[id] == None or not self.vc[id].is_connected():
            self.vc[id] = await channel.connect()
            print("It is: ", self.vc[id], " in join_vc")

            if self.vc[id] == None:
                await ctx.send("Could not connect to the voice channel ")
                return None
        else:
            await self.vc[id].move_to(channel)
            print(self.vc[id])
            
            
    def search_YT(self, search):
        queryString = parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
        htmContent = request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + queryString)
        searchResults = re.findall('/watch\?v=(.{11})', htmContent.read().decode())
        return searchResults[0:10]
        
    def extract_YT(self, url):
        with YoutubeDL(self.YTDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try:
                info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            except:
                return False
            
        return {
            'link': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + url,
            'thumbnail': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + url + '/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCOADEI4CSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLD5ul4xKN-IUfez6KIW_j5y70mlig',
            'source': info['formats'][0]['url'],
            'title': info['title']
        }
        
    def play_next(self, ctx):
        id = int(ctx.guild.id)
        if not self.is_playing[id]:
            return
        if self.queueIndex[id] + 1 < len(self.musicQueue[id]):
            self.i_playing[id] = True
            self.queueIndex[id] += 1
            
            song = self.musicQueue[id][self.queueIndex[id]][0]
            message = self.now_playing_embed(ctx, song)
            coro = ctx.send(embed=message)
            fut = run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, self.bot.loop)
            try:
                fut.result()
            except:
                pass
                
            self.vc[id].play(discord.FFmegPCMAudio(
                song['source'], ** self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))
        else:
            self.queueIndex[id] += 1
            self.is_playing[id] = False
    
    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        id = int(ctx.guild.id)
        if self.queueIndex[id] < len(self.musicQueue[id]):
            self.is_playing[id] = True
            self.is_paused[id] = False
            
            await self.join_VC(ctx, self.musicQueue[id][self.queueIndex[id]][1])
            
            song = self.musicQueue[id][self.queueIndex[id]][0]
            message = self.now_playing_embed(ctx, song)
            await ctx.send(embed=message)
            
            self.vc[id].play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
                song['source'], **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))
        else:
            await ctx.send("There are no songs in queue to be played")
            self.queueIndex[id] += 1
            self.is_playing = False
        
    @ commands.command(
        name="join",
        aliases=["j","jion"],
        help=""
    )
    async def join(self, ctx):
        id = int(ctx.guild.id)
        if ctx.author.voice:
            userChannel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
            print("Before assignment self.vc[id] = ", self.vc[id])
            await self.join_VC(ctx, userChannel)
            print("After assignment self.vc[id] = ", self.vc[id])
            await ctx.send(f'Rhythmus has joined {userChannel}')

        else:
            await ctx.send("You need to be in a voice channel")
        
    @ commands.command(
        name="leave",
        aliases=["l","laeve"],
        help=""
    )
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        id = int(ctx.guild.id)
        self.is_playing[id] = self.is_paused[id] = False
        self.musicQueue[id] = []
        self.queueIndex[id] = 0
        if self.vc[id] != None:
            await ctx.send("Rhythmus has left the voice channel")
            await self.vc[id].disconnect()
```

Comment: The main program is pibot.py with the code, with the semi colons to added after to show the end of a line:

from discord_components import ComponentsBot;

from music_cog import music_cog;

bot = ComponentsBot(command_prefix='?');        

bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot)); 

bot.run('Token')

Comment: most of your code imports aren't properly formatted

Comment: Never mind, it's just not in a code block

Comment: Do you have the proper intents for voice? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68914578/15982771

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating my version of discord.py which I had at a lower version so discord_components would work with it. I then adapted my main code to work with the new version and without discord_components.

Code: [image of main code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0q5I.png)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)